# VBA Trying to Scrape HTML Option Selected InnerText from DropDown box

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am new to VBA and trying to create a web scraper to create a report from one our applications.  It is a vendor created environment, but we own the data.  I am able to navigate to the site and pull most of the data I need; however, I have hit a brick wall with trying to pull whether the time was AM or PM. The AM or PM is essential because we require services 24 hours a day and we get charged for short notice calls.

The HTML code is:

```
<td>

<select name="collectionInfoBox:generalInformationBox:agencyNotifiedDate:timeSelector">

<option value="0">AM</option>

<option selected="selected" value="1">PM</option>

</select>

</td>
```

My VBA code is:

```
set nt = htmlDoc.getElementsByName("collectionInfoBox:generalInformationBox:agencyNotifiedDate:timeSelector")
ws.Cells(1, 7).Value = nt.Item(nt.SelectedIndex).innerText
```

I found this code as an answer to a question posted that seemed to be similar to mine.  I get a Run-time error '438':  Object doesn't support this property or method on the ws.Cells(1, 7).Value line.

As I said, I've only been using VBA for a few days, so any advice on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to narrow down which thing is the problem.  Does `ws.Cells(1,7).Value = 3` work?  Does it fail if you remove `innerText`?  Divide and conquer.

Comment: ws.Cells(1, 7).Value = 3 works.  Removing the innerText still results in the same runtime error.

Comment: Then keep going.  Does `nt.SelectedIndex` work?  Can you print/echo `nt` to make sure you actually got something?

Comment: I changed it to ws.Cells(1, 7).Value = nt.Item(selectedIndex).innerText and am now returning both AM and PM in my report.  I am unsure how to get just the selected value (in this case it is PM).

Comment: If I do ws.Cells(1, 7).Value = nt.Item(selectedIndex) it returns [object HTMLSelectElement]

Comment: How do you get both?  `nt.Item(0)` should return the first, `nt.Item(1)` should return the second.

Comment: In more detail: The method `getElementsByName()` creates a node collection, just like `getElementsByClassName()` and `getElementsByTagName()`. All elements in the node collection are addressed via their index. The first index in a node collection is `0`. Your code only needs to be extended by this index, then the selected option will be output: `htmlDoc.getElementsByName("collectionInfoBox:generalInformationBox:agencyNotifiedDate:timeSelector")(0)` However, this only works if the attribute `selected` in the html document is also set for a different selection for the selected `option` tag.

Comment: If I do the nt.item(nt.selectedIndex) it says that the obejct doesn't support the property or method.  If I remove the "nt" before the selectedIndex, it gives both "labels" that could be selelcted.  By using (0) I will return just the "AM" as expected; however, this data is input by another person.  I am trying to pull the value of what she inputs to that drop down.  In this case, I know it's should be "PM".  Is there a way to get the "selected value"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my testing, I had to use the method `findElementsByName`, as `getElementsByName` was not valid?  At any rate, if you change your evaluation of the result to be `= nt.item(1).Value` you will get either a Zero or a One.  Zero is AM and One is PM.  Additionally note that the object `nt` is a list, and it may have zero or more results.  Your specification looks like it will only get one result.  But to be sure, you should always check if `nt.count` is zero or greater and handle that result as well.

If you do not know the static text of the selections, you can also do this

```
Dim vals() As String
vals = Split(nt.Item(1).Text, Chr(10))
ws.Cells(1, 7) = vals(nt.Item(1).Value)
```

**EDIT:**
If not using Selenium then this is your access to that element

```
Dim vals() As String, n As Integer
n = nt.Item.selectedIndex
vals = Split(nt.Item.innerText, " ")
Cells(1, 7).Value = vals(n)
```

Comment: I am beginning to wonder if I do not have a reference loaded (I have the HTML Object Library and Internet Controls) or something because I cannot use findElementsByName.  If I leave nt set to what's in my code above and do ws.Cells(1, 7).Value = nt.Item(1).Value  I get Run-Time error 91: Object variable or With block. variable not set on the ws.Cells(1, 7).Value = nt.Item(1).Value.  I copied your code and it is giving the same error only on the vals = Split(nt.Item(1).Text, Chr(10)) line.

Comment: My apologies, I assumed you were using Selenium to access the web page.  Here is what you need to use instead:
`Dim vals() As String, n As Integer
 n = nt.Item.selectedIndex
vals = Split(nt.Item.innerText, " ")
Cells(1, 7).Value = vals(n)`

Comment: Thank you so much!  I don't have enough reputation to cast a vote.  Unfortunately, I cannot use Selenium as it is a work computer.

Comment: should the above code work for another dropdown selection box that has several choices not just AM/PM?

Comment: it will work on any dropdown

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I may have to start another question on here because I can't seem to get the other ones to work... The values 3 above seem to be picked up.